# Dagger @Provides in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, dagger

I'm trying to understand Dagger. I created applicationInjector class :

```
class BaseApplication : DaggerApplication() {
override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication>? {
    return DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this)?.build()
}
```

}

And here's my AppComponent

```
@Component(
    modules = [AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        ActivityBuilderModules::class]
)

interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<BaseApplication> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application?): Builder?
        fun build(): AppComponent?
    }
}
```

Now what I want to do is to to inject simple String to Activity (really basic, right ?)

In Java it works like this :

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilderModules {

@ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract fun contributeAuthActivity() : AuthActivity

//JAVA
    @Provides
    public static String provideTestString() {
        return "TEST "
    }
```

however we don't have static function in Kotlin, right ? And it needs to be static cause I'm getting an error :

```
error: com.example.kotlintests.di.ActivityBuilderModules is abstract and has instance @Provides methods. Consider making the methods static or including a non-abstract subclass of the module instead.
public abstract interface AppComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<com.example.kotlintests.BaseApplication> {
```

I tried with package level function but it didn't work. How can I add provideTestString function in Kotlin ?

Comment: put it in the companion object and annotate it with `@JvmStatic`

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work , but I will try again. Thanks

Comment: Or put that in a concrete module class and include that other module as well.